# Error saving an object for a column with many to one relation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jackson

This is my school entity.

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")

public class School{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "school", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Teacher> Teachers= new HashSet<>();

//constructor, getter and setter
```

This is my teacher class

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")

public class Teacher{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String userId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SCHOOL_ID")
    @JsonProperty("schoolId")
    @JsonBackReference
    private School school;

//constructor, getter and setter
```

My teacher controller looks like this

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Create new teacher", response = Teacher.class)
    @ApiParam
    @RequestMapping(value = "/teacher", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Teacher createTeacher(@RequestBody Teacher t) {      
        return teacherService.saveTeacher(t);
    }
```

My service which just calls the CrudRepository save method.

```
    public Teacher saveTeacher(Teacher t) {
        return teacherRepository.save(t);

    }
```

This is how my JSON looks like when creating a teacher. A school object with id = 1 exists in my db

```
{
    "userId":"jDoe",
    "schoolId":1
}
```

This is the error I get

```
 Could not resolve parameter [0] in public com.lace.schoolApp.model.Teacher com.lace.schoolApp.controller.TeacherController.createTeacher(com.lace.schoolApp.model.Teacher): JSON parse error: Unresolved forward references for: ; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.UnresolvedForwardReference: Unresolved forward references for: 
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 7, column: 1]Object id [1] (for `com.lace.schoolApp.model.School`) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 16].
2021-02-10 17:04:11.959  WARN 11628 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unresolved forward references for: ; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.UnresolvedForwardReference: Unresolved forward references for: 
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 7, column: 1]Object id [1] (for `com.lace.schoolApp.model.School`) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 16].]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch the School details using `schoolId` passed in the request payload from `scholRepository` first in your `teacherService`. 
Then set the school object to Teacher and save it

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class TeacherService{

@Autowired
private SchoolRepository schoolRepository;

@Autowired
private TeacherRepository teacherRepository;

@Transactional
public Teacher saveTeacher(Teacher t) {

        School school = schoolRepository.findById(t.getschool().getId()); // schoolId from request //Fetch school details
        t.setSchool(school); // set school details.
        return teacherRepository.save(t); // save teacher details with existing school

    }
}
```

```
{
    "userId":"jDoe",
    "schoolId":{
       "id":1
       }
}
```

Comment: What is my t.getSchoolId method suppose to look like? I don't have any method like that atm.

Comment: @valor1100 it should be `t.getSchoolId()`

Comment: Yeah but I am still not sure what getSchoolId() in my teacher class should look like. How will it return the school id. I'd imagine it would look like something like this in my teacher class? return this.getSchool().getId(); but this returns null.

Comment: @valor1100 you need to create the getters and setters method. If you are using eclipse then you can easily generate it from the path `Source -> Generate Getters and Setters`

Comment: yes I have the default getters and setter. But non of them match to getSchoolId() inside my teacher class. I have getters and setter for id, userId, school.

Comment: You should have one for schoolId

Comment: t.getSchoolId() - is the passed in schoolId from request payload `"schoolId":1`

Comment: I am using the sclipse getter/setter option. I am confused though as to why I would have a schoolId getter/setter when my Teacher class doesn't have that field. It has the school field but not schooldId.

Comment: @valor1100 got you, you don't need the `schoolId` for in Teacher just pass the schoolId from request to `schoolRepository.findById(schoolId)`

Comment: yeah but isn't that just getting mapped to school because of @JsonProperty("schoolId")

Comment: I get a schoolId cannot be resolved to a variable if I do just schoolId or t.schoolId

Comment: Yes, You need to change the request payload in this case. refer answer

Comment: Your repo call will be `schoolRepository.findById(t.getschool().getId())` or `schoolRepository.findById(t.getschoolId().getId())` just check this

Comment: do you mean like the JSON request? Like send a schoold object instead of schoolId?

Comment: Yes correct we need schoold object instead of schoolId

Comment: tried that it seems like t.getschool() just returns null. So I get a null pointed exception.

Comment: Ohh I realize you changed the request payload. Is there any other way around it. I know it works that way.

Comment: request payload you have sent in?

Comment: is it possible to accomplish this with the original payload request I put?

Comment: Yes it is possible but you need to add the `private transient Long schoolId;` in your Teacher

Comment: `private transient Long schoolId;` in your teacher class, create getter/setter then use `schoolRepository.findById(t.getschoolId())`

Comment: @valor1100 did you try the above?

Comment: thanks that works. Although I realize that I don't necessarily need to make this call `schoolRepository.findById(t.getschoolId())`. If I just do this then it works as well.


`School s = new School();`

`s.setId(t.getschoolId());`

`t.setSchool(s);`

`return teacherRepository.save(t);`

Any drawbacks to doing it this way?

Comment: You can do this, but if you have passed any invalid `schoolId` in the request then it will create that record in the school table with passed in id

Comment: @valor1100, you can accept this as the answer as it solves your problem so that others will know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another field for reference like **schoolId**:

```
@Entity
public class Teacher{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String userId;

    @Column(name="school_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonProperty("schoolId")
    private Long schoolId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "school_id")
    private School school;
```

With request body:

```
{
    "userId": "jDoe",
    "schoolId": 1
}
```

Comment: Although I don't get the error anymore and the call goes through. In my db it is storing null in the school_id column.

Comment: {
    "userId":"jDoe",
    "schoolId":1
}